# building a search API that supports facets as well as pagination

Tags: node.js, sqlite, facet

I am building a search API to support a faceted search interface. My confusion stems from also needing to support pagination of records. At its most basic, my API consists of

- a resource: `resource`
- searchable terms: an array of terms: `terms[]`
- data returned: an array of objects: `data[{}]`

  - record: an object with each field as a key `record{}`
  - number of records: `num`
  - offset in the database: `page`
- facets that allow narrowing the returned data: a subset of the keys of record `record{}`: `facets[]`

For what its worth, my backend is SQLite and nodejs.

My problem arises from the fact that I am returning only `num` records as a `page` of results. Given that only `num` records exist in the client at any given time, facets would narrow result only in that `num` records. However, I want to narrow results over the *entire* result set. That means I have to send back queries for each facet click. With each click on a facet, I have to rebuild my original query, this time including the cumulative facets clicked, and get the results back to the client. Am I on the right track? What would be the most efficient dataset (structure and content) to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track. You can't implement that search and filter only in the UI unless you send your whole DB/table to the UI.

What you need to send from the UI to the backend:

- filter terms (facets), so you can build the `AND` clauses in your query
- *page number* and *page size*
- sort clause - unless you have just one way to sort things. But make sure your queries are sorted.